# making a self made html fixer handle universal tags

Tags: python, html, parsing

what this following code does is, it takes a set open tag and a end tag, and if there are any unclosed tags of that type, it will close them. the problem with this is, it wont handle font tags, as there is more to font tags then just `<font>`. i was thinking that there would be a way to use regex to have it match the tags before hand then pass it to this html fixer so that way it could handle any type of tag. any suggestions? the regex would probably look like `<+[\w ="\']+?>` for the start tag and `</+[\w ="\']+?>` for the end tag. and this is in 3.x if you are wondering about the odd syntax i use.

```
def check_html(otag, etag, text):
    ret = ['f', text, otag, etag] if text.count(otag) != text.count(etag) else ['a', text, otag, etag]
    return fix_html(ret)

def fix_html(x):
    grade, text, otag, etag = x
    ret = [otag + text if text.endswith(etag) else s for s in text.split()] if grade == 'f' else text
    ret = [text + etag if text.startswith(otag) else s for s in ret] if grade == 'f' else text
    return ret[0] if grade == 'f' else ret
```

Comment: Repeat after me: Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML. Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML. Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML. Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML. Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML.

Comment: lol the whole point of this is so that it does not use regex

Comment: the only thing that would use regex is finding tags that have arguments inside of them. then it would pass those tags to my parser

Comment: This won't work for _any_ tag with attributes—`a`, `div`, `p`, etc. Nor will it work for empty tags like `<br />`. Nor will it work for any tags inside other tags, like `<div><span>foo</div>`. And probably plenty more besides. Writing your own HTML parser that handles illegal tag soup is hard, even for just a small subset of HTML. And trying to do it with simple string operations instead of by building a parser is even harder.

Comment: it is going to be used for a chat interface and font tags will be the only acceptable ones, and as for the attribute tags, that is why i wanted to match them before and send those matched tags through my parser. in python i cant do operations between string and regex objects, such as string.count(regexobject). but if there was a way to do something like this then it could handle the attributes inside of the tags